# Shiro and SessionContext CDI => "anonymous"

Tags: resources, shiro, sessioncontext

I want to get my current loggin User in my EJB Container.
I built an CDI - EJB Webapplication with Shiro for Security.

My problem is now, in my EJB Class the sessionContext is everytime "anonymous"

```
@Resource
private SessionContext sessionContext;

String userEmail = sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
```

I don´t know, set Shiro this automaticly or should I set sessionContext?
Can anybody help me?

The problem is the connection from CDI ---> EJB or why is it "anonymous"

Answer (score 0):

@Resource is not context-aware. You want to use @Inject instead.

Comment: @Inject does not work (in my glassfish4 instance).  
Getting  
`[glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=57 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1399386171108] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [SessionContext] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private de.gfz.rz.idm.services.intern.impl.AccountServiceIntranetBean.sessionContext]`

Comment: Is your project EE6 or EE7?

Comment: EE7 - currently running on the newest promotion build of GF 4.0.1 (build 5)